# wx.dataview.TreeListCtrl changing column title

Tags: wxpython, python-3.6, dataview

I'm using the `TreeListCtrl` in Python3 and am building a list of items within this column, with the objective to change the current column title and update the list of the items within which.

How can I go about changing the column title in the simplest manner?
I tried deleting the column with `DeleteColumn(0)/ClearColumns()` and rebuilding the column with a new title and updated list, but a new column was built every time.